# Using MySQL and PHP with a Chrome Packaged App?

Tags: google-chrome-app

My dream is to build a completely client side application where the app is powered by MySQL, PHP, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Then, a customized version of Chrome would manage all of the user experience.

Chrome Packaged Apps looks like the closest thing to this... is it possible to get PHP and MySQL distributed with a Chrome Packaged App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distributing PHP and MySQL as is is not possible with a Chrome packaged app. Packaged apps cannot include arbitrary binaries or the ability to run them.

It may be theoretically possible to have a version of PHP and MySQL that are built for [Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/) (NaCl), which is a safe way for native code to be run within Chrome's sandbox. However, it would be a significant undertaking to recompile PHP, MySQL, and their dependencies so that they build and run within the NaCl runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to take a look at the various options for local storage of objects here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/resource-panel. Some of these provide features very similar to that of a SQLite database.

Mihai is totally right about the inability to run PHP. Your primary option is to write the code which manages routing, templates etc in Javascript with the help of a framework such as [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/).

Good luck!